# css image background use position and stretch at the same time

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm create a list of avatar for my user to choose on my website. The avatars are in a big image with 5 sub-image per row and 5 sub-image per column. So this by using image background position, I can display one of the 25 possible choice. For example, my sub-image size is 160X160, and I want to display row 3 column 2. The css will be

```
<img class="avatar-icon img-thumbnail" style="background-position: -160px -320px; background-image: url('/images/logos/Avatar_0.png')">
```

It works great. Then I found the avatar is a little bit big in some situation. And I want to stretch the background after it is positioned. In the example above, I still want to display from area from (-160px,-320px) to (-320px,-480px). But I want to stretch it to 50%, so imag size will be 80x80. I tried the background parameters but didn't find a good combination. Is there a css way to do it? (without duplicating the big image to a 50% smaller one)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<div>` or `<span>` for background properties instead of applying on image tag.

You can achieve avatar scaling in 2 ways:

1) By scaling both position parameters and image size, i.e.
`background-position: -80px -160px; background-size: 50% auto;`.

2) If you don't want to change the position parameters, you can simply scale with the transform property.
`transform: scale(0.5);`

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried but cannot work it out by using span. Span itself cannot hold the defined size unless there is something inside it, like text.

Comment: @Chris For using `<span>`, you will need to give it `display: inline-block;` to work.